# Return value of loop variable with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm looking a quick solution to return value in loop using variable

There is base code

```
var origins = [
    {level: '1', hp: 5600},
    {level: '2', hp: 7600},
    {level: '3', hp: 9600}
];

var text1 = "";
var text2 = "";

for (var key in origins) {
       if (origins.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
         text1 = origins[key].level;
         text2 = origins[key].hp;
       }
    }
```

I'm trying to call loop variable

```
console.log(text1 + " " + text2)
```

It gave me an output that I didn't want:

```
3 9600
```

I'm looking an excepted result of output would be like this:

```
1 5600
2 7600
3 9600
```

EDIT:
There is JSfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/mttweck6/2/

Comment: did you put the console.log in the loop or outside of the loop

Comment: Cannot add in the loop for some reason, I was trying to add HTML content outside of loop.

Comment: why can't you put it inside the loop

Comment: By "return value" do you mean this is in a function and you are returning by using `return` for your two variables?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek he is using console.log

Comment: @NendoTaka He is using console log to show the value.

Comment: @Ivan try using the loop in my answer and see if it works

Comment: I need to add loop variable inside of HTML content would be like

tooltip : {content : "<span style=\"font-weight:bold;\">Level</span><br />" + text1 + "<br /> <span>HP</span>" + text2}
   }

Comment: This would be easier to understand if we had some html to see what you were trying to do.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the text variables? Are you making a list of hp and level?

Comment: Wait a min, I make a JSfiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mttweck6/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put the console.log in the loop or add to one text variable like final. See below

```
var origins = [
{level: '1', hp: 5600},
{level: '2', hp: 7600},
{level: '3', hp: 9600}
];

var text1 = "";
var text2 = "";
var final = "";

for (var key in origins) {
    if (origins.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        text1 = origins[key].level;
        text2 = origins[key].hp;
        final += "Level: " + text1 + '\n' + "HP: " + text2 + '\n';
    }
}





//I need to get external variable that would exeute in loop
alert(final);



//Excepted Result as one alert with output:
//Level 1: 5600
//Level 2: 7600
//Level 3: 9600
```

Comment: For some reason I can't add inside of loop, take a look  
http://www.jsfiddle.net/mttweck6/2

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mttweck6/6/ see if this gives you any ideas will keep working on it though

Comment: That would work as enough, please edit your answer so I can vote your answer as accepted

Comment: which one first or second

Comment: First one, these variables shouldn't be  inside of loop

Comment: Edit made let me know if you need any more help

Answer (score 3):

I think this might help you :

```
var origins = [
{level: '1', hp: 5600},
{level: '2', hp: 7600},
{level: '3', hp: 9600}
];

var text1 = "";
var text2 = "";
var s= "";

for (var key in origins) {
   if (origins.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      text1 = origins[key].level;
      text2 = origins[key].hp;
      s += '\n' + "Level " + text1 + ": " + text2;
   }
}
```

Then later do
    `alert(s);`

Comment: It gave me an output when I use "final" variable
:


undefined undefined
undefined undefined
undefined undefined

Comment: Try an other name, final must be reserved.

Comment: I have changed a bit the code, it should display what you want.

Comment: It worked! no more help, well we had 3 correct answers here, sorry I should mark the first answer, no offense...

Answer (score 2):

```
var origins = [
    {level: '1', hp: 5600},
    {level: '2', hp: 7600},
    {level: '3', hp: 9600}
];

var text1 = "";
var text2 = "";

for (var key in origins) {
   if (origins.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
     text1 = origins[key].level;
     text2 = origins[key].hp;
     console.log(text1 + " " + text2);
   }
}
```

Edit: If you would like to save the results as an entire string

```
var origins = [
    {level: '1', hp: 5600},
    {level: '2', hp: 7600},
    {level: '3', hp: 9600}
];

var text1 = "";
var text2 = "";
var result = ""; // String to print

for (var key in origins) {
   if (origins.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
     text1 = origins[key].level;
     text2 = origins[key].hp;
     result += text1 + " " + text2 + "\n";
   }
}

alert(result);
```

If you would like to display this in HTML each on their own line, just replace `result += text1 + " " + text2 + "\n";` with `result += text1 + " " + text2 + "<br>";` and `alert(result);` with `document.getElementById("myelem").innerHTML = result;`

Comment: What if I get these text1 and text2 variables into HTML content? take a look at  
http://www.jsfiddle.net/mttweck6/2

Comment: I assume you mean displaying or printing them all at once. If so, I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: It worked! sorry it seems chaos, I would give a mark to your answer as accepted but I should mark at first place. Sorry, no offense..

Comment: @Ivan I'm heartbroken ;)